# Data Trigger where value is not Null

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I want to set some text where the value is not null.
XAML:

```
<TextBlock >
   <TextBlock.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
         <Setter Property="Text" Value="solved"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Report}" Value="{x:Null}">
                   <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
                 </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Note: Here **Report** is *STRING* which has some random value like (e.g 11,112,11a)

it shows **solved** in every row which seems that data trigger is not working.

but its working with this code with this random value (e.g 11,112,11a)

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Report}"/>
```

I want **Solved** *as text* instead of that random values (e.g 11,112,11a) otherwise **blank** where there is no value.

Comment: Is it feasible for you adding another property "sibling" to Report, let's say "ReportText", to the viewmodel? Also it would be useful if you show us some code where the Report property lays.

Comment: Your code looks right. I've had trouble already using {x:Null} for the value. Sometimes just setting the value = "" and then back to {x:Null} can fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a converter like so:

`xaml`:

```
xmlns:cnv="clr-namespace:Converters"
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Report, Converter={cnv:CustomNullToStringConverter NotNullValue=Solved,NullValue=''}}"/>
```

Converter:

```
class CustomNullToStringConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public string NullValue { get; set; }
    public string NotNullValue { get; set; }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string && String.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string)) return NullValue;
        if (value == null) return NullValue;
        return NotNullValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```